# Form elements not clickable even with positive z-index and positioned. Form on animated card flip DIV

Tags: html, css, forms, z-index

I am trying to get it so that the user can submit comments on the "back" of an element that does a 3d flip using css animate. However I cannot get the form clickable.

I have tried using z-index on the positioned element.

You can tab into the form and enter data and submit without issue. You just cannot click it.

What am I missing here?

Thank you for your help.

```css
.entry_wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 1.5em auto;
    }
.entry_wrapper {
    -webkit-perspective: 2000;
    }

.entry_wrapper:hover .face {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
.face {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 5px #000000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
.face .back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    border: solid white 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: grey;
    z-index: 30;

    }
.entry {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
.entry_img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
.entry img {
    Width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    }
.entry_img p {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }
.entry_footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.8);
    }
.comment {
    width: 66%;
    background: #cccccc;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    }
.comment p {
    margin: 2px 5px;
    }
.comment_name {
    font-size: .8em;
    
    }
.comment_name span {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:10px;
    }
.add_comment {
    width: 66%;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto;
    background: #cccccc;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 50;
    }
#comment_form {
    z-index: 50;
    }
```

```html
<main>
      
              <div class="entry_wrapper">
                <div class="face">
                  <div class="entry">
                    <div class="entry_img">
                      <img src="img/family.jpg">
                      <p>Birth of first daughter Sophia.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry_footer">
                    <p>Like?</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">
                    <div class="comment">
                      <p> I really like this picture.</p>
                        <div >
                          <p class="comment_name">By: Matthew <span class="date">On: Nov 5th, 2014</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form id="comment_form" action="comment_submit.php">
                      <input type="submit">
                    </form>
                      <textarea name="comment1" class="add_comment" form="comment_form" placeholder="test"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        
        
        <div class="entry_wrapper">
          <div class="entry">
            <div class="entry_img">
              <img src="img/summit.jpg">
              <p>I made it to the top!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="entry_footer">
            <p>Like?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
```

Comment: So you wnat the image to show first and then they click the image to spin around to the contact form .. is that correct?

Comment: you can put the back at the front and make it turn when the website loads if you turn it again you can use the form.

Comment: Billy, onhover it spins to the back. That is working correctly, however I have a form on the back that isn't working correctly. I need to be sure the form is clickable in order to make it active. 

I like Stefan's solution and I think it will work. Creative idea. I will go and check it out for a solution.

Comment: Stefan, that was a good idea, however it doesn't work out. The problem is with backface-visibility: hidden; However the animation doesn't work without that. I still cannot get this to work.